# Responsive SPA and VueJS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, vue.js, responsive

In the past, due to lacking any real CSS skill and design capabilities, I just started out with bootstrap.  VueJS looks very interesting to me for my next project.  I started down a path with it but after some readings and finding [vue-strap](https://yuche.github.io/vue-strap/) (only working with 1x currently as I understand it), I thought I should verify that Vue + Bootstrap is not only a viable solution but a common one with minimal project setup, thinking WebPack.

I also would be curious if there is a better combo option with Vue to get the 'out of the box' responsiveness bootstrap gives.

Vue is fundamentally different from other frameworks that I used and I'm not even sure I'm asking a sensible question, so knowing that is useful too.

Comment: Vue Strap ship some already done components for VueJS.You are still able and allowed to use pure, normal, vanilla Bootstrap and integrate it in your SPA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for complete SPA + responsiveness framework with VueJS, I definitely suggest Quasar Framework: http://quasar-framework.org/guide/

It comes with complete, responsive CSS, almost all necessary components (with missing coming soon). It is what you want as you don't have to combine things yourself etc as it gives you complete foundation to develop SPA which will work perfectly fine on all devices.

It is like Ion (which works with Angular), but with VueJS

Comment: (POTENTIAL OFF TOPIC) I did come across that.  My concern is that with something like VueJS you're already relying on a 'smaller' (but growing as I understand it) community by itself, and then a framework on top of that means you're relying on 2 small communities.  Do you have any insight into the the strength of the two communities?

Comment: VueJS is definitely not small community... It was maybe a year or more ago, but definitely not now.